# How to add protractor option in Gruntfile

Tags: selenium, grep, gruntjs, protractor

I am able to run a single protractor testcase with arguments:

```
protractor --specs='tests/e2e/login.js' --grep="SingleLoginTest"
```

I have protractor task in Gruntfile as:

```
protractor: {
  options: {
    keepAlive: false,
    configFile: "./config/protractorConf.js"
  },
  e2eTest: {
    options: {
      args: {
        specs: ['tests/e2e/login.js'],
        grep: "SingleLoginTest"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When I try to run it with grunt it runs all testcases of login.

How to add protractor options in grunt?

Answer (score 1):

It works with suites for me:

inside conf file:

```
suites: {
    login: 'tests/e2e/login.js',
},
```

inside gruntfile:

```
e2eTest: {
    options: {
      args: {
        suite: "login"
      }
    }
  }
```

Btw I use `grunt-protractor-runner` I believe it is also passing arguments so `grunt e2eTest --specs='tests/e2e/login.js'` should work as well.

Comment: I am able to pass --specs option in Gruntfile but not grep option. I figured out we have to pass it in jasmineNodeOpts and that is not supported by `grunt-protractor-runner` which I am using. I might create a pull request for it, I have patch. Thanks!